# A Proof tree in Tikz

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I would like to draw a proof tree, which resembles exactly the below proof tree
[image]

Since I'm a newbie in Tikz, I tried, but I did get this(see picture below), which far away what I want to draw (no arrows, the boxes not bold, the position of the boxes...).

Could anyone help me achieve the desired result?
[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
  every node/.style = {shape=rectangle,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white,}]]
  \node {S1|\textbf{R3}}
    child { node {S2|\textbf{R1}} }
       child { node {S3|\textbf{R5}}
        child { node {S5|\textbf{R4}} }
        child { node {S6|\textbf{R6}} } }
    child { node {S4|\textbf{R2}} };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I had a bit of time, here is a better implementation.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    csw/.style = { % connect from center to south west
        edge from parent path={ 
            (\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode.south west)
        },
    },
    cse/.style = {   % connect from center to south east
        edge from parent path={
            (\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode.south east)
        },
    },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    sibling distance=5em,
    level 2/.style = {sibling distance=10em},
    -{Stealth[length=5mm, width=2mm]}, grow=up,  % use arrowe, grows the graph up. 
    every node/.style =
        {shape=rectangle split,   % use two-parts rectangular nodes 
        rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split horizontal, 
        draw, thick, align=center, % draw thick lines.
        text width=1.5em},
    every two node part/.style = { % set the style of the second part
        font=\bfseries,            % so we can avoid all the \textbf{}
    }
    ]
    \node{S1 \nodepart{two} R3}
        child [csw] { node {S2 \nodepart{two} R1} }
            child [thick] { node {S3 \nodepart{two} R5 }
                % we need to reset the thickness here, otherwise is inherited    
                child [csw, thin] { node {S5 \nodepart{two} R4} }
                child [cse, thin] { node {S6 \nodepart{two} R6} } 
              }
              child [cse]{ node {S4 \nodepart{two} R2} 
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image: refined result]

#### Original answer

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
    ->, >=stealth, grow=up,  % use arrowe, grows the graph up. 
    every node/.style = {shape=rectangle split,   % use two-parts rectangular nodes 
        rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split horizontal, 
        draw, thick, align=center, % draw thick lines.
    top color=white,}]
    \node  {S1 \nodepart{two}\textbf{R3}}
        child { node {S2 \nodepart{two}\textbf{R1}} }
        child { node {S3 \nodepart{two}\textbf{R5}}
                child { node {S5 \nodepart{two}\textbf{R4}} }
                child { node {S6 \nodepart{two}\textbf{R6}} } }
                child { node {S4 \nodepart{two}\textbf{R2}} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

It should be changed to send the arrows to the option `edge from parent path` in the manual, and to make the two parts the same size (look at the Shape Library, shapes with multipart, in the same manual).

Comment: add ` text width=5mm,` to center the 2 box

Comment: how can I decrease the space between the nodes?

Comment: sibling distance for space reduce, thanks for the help